# Question list on profile page not vertically aligned

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, profile-page

There's something wrong with the vertical alignment on the [Questions tab of a profile page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/295232/glorfindel?tab=questions&sort=newest):

[image]
<sub>(click to enlarge)</sub>

On the [home page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/), which uses a similar list but without the Favorite column, the vertical alignment is correct.

(Tested in the latest Firefox, Safari and Chrome on macOS Catalina.)

Comment: ok, I must say that those red lines are much worse. I don't see them. What did you do?

Comment: It appears to be related to _answer_ vs _answers_.

Comment: _box-sizing: border-box;_ is the difference between both pages.

Comment: @JeffDarwood apologies for the lack of freehand circles, but the lines are there to make it clearer that the alignment is off.

Comment: Yet another pluralisation bug @dfhwze

Answer (score 3):

I just noticed this myself as well, and thought about reporting it, only to find this post.

I decided to dig a bit deeper and I believe to have found the root cause. Take a look at the next two screenshots:

Answered question:
[image]

Unanswered question:
[image]

Question with multiple answers:
[image]

You can see that the width of the div's are different:
Questions with only 1 answer have a width of 51.15 and unanswered questions and questions with multiple answers have a width of 56.85. This of course boils down to the difference between "answers" and "answer", and the fact that the CSS uses a `min-width` of 44 px. Using a fixed with resolves the alignment issues.

If I tweak the CSS and make the width's equal, at 51.15, they all line up perfectly:
[image]

Answer (score 3):

This is now fixed. As Luuklag pointed out, the issue had to do with the "answers" cell having different widths for questions with 1 answer or more than one answer**s** (with the extra "s" accounting for a few more pixels). The entire section of votes/answers/views boxes now have a `min-width` set that will ensure that the left margin of the question titles are now once again vertically-aligned.

Note: this is still not fixed on the Spanish and Portuguese Stack Overflow sites (where the translations for answer/answers are a few pixels wider). However, a fix that works well everywhere is something that we are not going to do. The issue is incredibly subtle, and the page itself is queued up for getting a new UI (one that is responsive and will address these issues in a much better way than the current hacky fix).

---

> Profile questions page
> Subtle alignment issue
> All in a row now

Comment: Good to hear that this page is scheduled to become responsive. I think it is one of the last pages (the profile page) that is really hard to use on a small viewport. Is there a more accurate estimate then 6-8 units of time regarding when it will receive some much needed TLC?

Comment: No timeline for this page in general. But I know that work has actually commenced in the long-awaited project of removing all of the mobile views and getting everything responsive across the site. But no idea when this specific view will get done.

Comment: Not fixed. See https://i.stack.imgur.com/ihBhm.png, which is from my profile here. The question titles are still misaligned.

Comment: I do see the changes made in the CSS @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog, but I think they are indeed not completely accurate. The min-width of 44 should work, but that is for the `<div>answers</div>`, it is set however at the `<div class=status-unaswered>` Seeing that the box surrounding the text is larger, the `min-width` would need to increase to something of about `57` to make it even. Or put the width on a different place in the CSS.

Comment: For those following at home, the new css is `.user-show-new .user-tab-content .user-questions .question-counts { min-width: 152px; }`

Comment: Ah I see @YaakovEllis, but that doesn't fix the issue for me. Width of that element with 1 answer is 153.917 and with no or multiple answers it is 161.45: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6pAE1.png

Comment: Have these changes been deployed already? I see a revision of yesterday in the footer (2021.7.7.39676) and it's still not aligned for me.

Comment: @Glorfindel for me it says rev 2021.7.8.39680, but still the bug persists., probably to do with my comment above.