# Misalignment on user bounty page when there is one answer vs. multiple answers

Tags: bug, design, profile-page, bounties

This is a very minor problem, but if we go to a user's bounty page (e.g. [this one](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/users/4136/mo?tab=bounties&sort=offered)), there is a misalignment between questions with 1 answer and questions with multiple answers.  I don't think this is intentional; it's inconsistent with the main page where 1-answer and non-1-answer questions are aligned.  I just thought I'd mention it.

Firefox for Linux Mint 81.0 (64-bit):

> [image]

Chromium Version 85.0.4183.121 (Official Build) Built on Ubuntu, running on LinuxMint 19.1 (64-bit):

> [image]

Comment: It's not just the Bounties tab: [Question list on profile page not vertically aligned](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/337259/295232)

Comment: Thanks.  I didn't see that post when I posted.  It's probably close enough to be considered a duplicate.