# 'Show full post' links in list of recently deleted posts are missing or not working

Tags: bug, moderator-tools, deleted-posts

♦ moderators have access to a [list of recently self-deleted posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/274642/admin-recently-self-deleted-is-not-showing-a-self-deleted-question) on their site. Answers in that list have a 'show full answer' link but it does not do anything, except take you to the top of the list. The link is entirely missing for questions. The link is supposed to make a network call to fetch the full post, but that doesn't even happen.

[image]

While you're at it, could you also have a look at the column alignment please? [(I know it's tricky ...)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/337259/question-list-on-profile-page-not-vertically-aligned#comment1223727_367265)

As @Makyen notes in the comments, similar links in the list of annotated posts *do* work.

<sub>NOTE: I have no objection against these self-deletions, I just needed an example or two.</sub>

Comment: It's probably a bit more broken than that. Given that the questions on the "Annotated Posts" page have a "show full question" button, which does work to show the question, the questions on the "Admin -> Recently Self-Deleted Posts" page are probably also supposed to have functional "show full question" buttons.